# How to pass in a .txt file to make a list of type string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a `.txt` file called `name.txt` that is in the same location as my `.ps1` script.
I want to pass in the `names.txt` into my `TestPS1.ps1` script as an array so I can iterate over different servers.
Code here:

```
$args1 = 'ServerName', 'SererName2'

$ArrComputers =  $args1

$OutArray = @()


Clear-Host
foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers) 
{
    .....  
}
```

Names.txt:

```
"ServerName","ServerName2"
```

As you can see I am using the `ArrComputers` variable to go over the list. I want to replace both strings, the list of strings, in `$args1` with an inputted list from `names.txt`. How would I do this?

Edit: Obviously if I run with `ServerName` as the name of the server this will not work. Pretend that every name in `Names.txt` is a valid server name

Answer (score 0):

I set `$args1` to be

```
$args1 = Get-Content .\names.txt
$args1 = $args1.Split(",")
```